# get index of element selected by Document.getElementByID("id_name")

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vbscript, autohotkey

For a page ("Bill4Time"), the Dashboard shows a table for displaying time entries and entering a new time entry but several control elements do not have ID's associated with them.  Interestingly enough, the control to add a new time entry line (an icon of a clipboard with a small plus sign in the lower right hand corner) always has the same index number (so I can select it with `Document.all("index_no")` to add a new time entry.  But once you edit that line by entering a new time entry, the control icon changes (to a generic clipboard, like all the other time entries in the table) and the index becomes dynamic -- and there is no id associated with that control.  However, I found that the parent element (i.e., the table cell) does have a unique ID which never changes (while it is the most recently added time entry) so currently I go to it (using `Document.getElementByID("unique_id").focus()`) and then send a {tab} to move over to the control element (and send {enter} to go to the correct details page).

If I could get the index number of the unique_id element, and increment that by one, I could more reliably get to the control I want, so my question is, if one has gotten a DOM element by id, how can one find its index number?

When I search here (or google) I get a lot of results for finding the index of the included elements within the parent, or results based on .selectedIndex and the like, and I suppose I could loop through all the DOM elements until I find the one with `ID = unique_id`, but there should be a better way to get an index number of a selected element.

TIA,

Comment: People will love this: Use `JQuery`.

Comment: I know about jquery only some -- are you saying it has a method for selecting the next element from a selected identified element?  Like  $("#unique_id").next_element?  What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least if doing it with IE and AutoHotkey this will give you the index

```
index := wb.document.getElementByID("unique_id").sourceIndex
```

But you don't need the index if you have the parent element

```
element := wb.document.getElementByID("unique_id").childnodes[0]
```

Also a lot of times elements that don't have an ID often have a Name or Class attribute, both of them can also be used to find the element you need...

Comment: But this doesn't work:
wb.Document.getElementByID("unque_id").childnodes[0].Click()

Comment: This works, so thank you!!!

`wb.Document.getElementByID("unque_id").firstElementChild.Click()`

Comment: Interestingly, there seems to be some offset in play, but this works: `wb.Document.All[wb.Document.getElementByID("unique_id").sourceIndex - 19].Click()`

Comment: And this also worked: `wb.Document.getElementByID("unique_id").childnodes.item[0].click()`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned looping, but I think that may be the way to do it since IDs are unique. Getting a matching element by its ID gives you that element, not an array of elements (like if you matched by class) which would all have an index.

If you know the ID of the table you want to focus on, you can do something like this if you don't want to use jQuery.

```
//get all the tables
var thisEleArr = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var indexOfTableIWant;

//loop through the array of tables
for (var i=0;i<thisEleArr.length;i++) {
    //if the id of the current table in the loop matches the known id
    if (thisEleArr[i].getAttribute('id')==='knownTableID') {
        //get the index of it
        indexOfTableIWant = i;
    }
}
```

My example using lists: https://jsfiddle.net/ksumarine/ga06n54u/

Comment: Sure, but since I want to access the element using Document.all("index_no"), I need the index of the DOM collection of elements, not the index of which table from the collection of tables.

Comment: Ah, I think I may have misunderstood which index you were looking for. My apologies!